# Javascript switch statement not working?

Tags: javascript

```
function decinumber(y){
var x = document.getElementById("areafield").value;
  if (x == 0){  alert(x);
   switch(y){
   case "one": x = 1; break;
   case "two": x = 2; break;
   case "three": x = 3; break;
   case "four": x = 4; break;
   case "five": x = 5; break;
   case "six": x = 6; break;
   case "seven": x = 7; break;
   case "eight": x = 8; break;
   case "nine": x = 9; break;
   case "zero": x = 0; break;
    }
   }
 }
```

The varible y in this function is an id, which the function gets from the button clicked in the HTML. The switch statement is not being accessible because when I put the alert statement within the switch braces it doesn't work, but when it is within the if braces it works.

Comment: so x is obviously zero, but y is not in range you listed in switch

Comment: You can't have an alert inside the `switch` braces, you can only have `case` and `default` statements there.

Comment: Also, you most likely don't want to use `x == 0` as this also returns true if e.g. x is an empty string. It is almost always safer to use `x === 0`

Comment: @Guffa his alert is before the switch statement, look closer

Comment: @Guffa right, OP says alert works *outside* switch, but inside if, and doesn't work *within the switch braces*

Comment: @AdrianToma: Read the question: *"when I put the alert statement within the switch braces it doesn't work, but when it is within the if braces it works"*

Comment: you could try to alert y , or maybe y == "one" for exemple

Comment: @guffa you are right :)

Comment: So, switch is probably works. OP just need to check `x` is altered *after* whole switch statement.

Comment: Are you sure `y` doesn't contain leading or following spaces?
`var x = 'zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine'.split('|').indexOf(y.toLowerCase().trim());` -- no ungly switch statement.

Comment: I hate these type of questions: _"Switch is not working"_... of course it is. `switch` works just fine, the issue isn't `switch` is how you use it. Never blame the tool for what it does in the hands of an even bigger tool. I don't mean this cruelly, but check the value of `y`, and I bet you'll find the issue is not `switch`, it's the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

It works Well here is the Fiddle

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CSHPm/)

```
function decinumber(y){
var x = 0;
if (x == 0){  alert(x);
switch(y){
case "one":{ x = 1;alert(1); break;}
case "two": x = 2; break;
case "three": x = 3; break;
case "four": x = 4; break;
case "five": x = 5; break;
case "six": x = 6; break;
case "seven": x = 7; break;
case "eight": x = 8; break;
case "nine": x = 9; break;
case "zero": x = 0; break;
 }
 }
 }

decinumber('one');
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy/paste you code and [adapted it for jsfiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/optyler/ns3Mh/) It's working for me :-)

You must check your `x` variable, it should be set to 0. And you must be sure that your `y` values are `===` the switch expression thats it :-)

EDIT : Add some code here after 
By the way, I prefer this syntax instead of `Switch ... case` one

```
function decinumber(y) {
    var hash = {
        'zero'  : 0,
        'one'   : 1,
        'two'   : 2,
        'three' : 3,
        'four'  : 4,
        'five'  : 5,
        'six'   : 6,
        'seven' : 7,
        'eight' : 8,
        'nine'  : 9        
    }

    // carefull, I'am replacing the value of the x input value, instead of just putting x
    var x = document.getElementById("areafield");
    if (x.value == 0 || x.value == '') {
      x.value = hash[y.toLowerCase()];
    }
 }
```

Comment: The variable y in this function is an id. I am not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: If the ID is a string it's OK, you must check the case too because === is case sensitive :-)
Maybe you can add a jsfiddle if the real code slightly differ ;-)